# Change a string based on a pattern

Tags: php, regex, string

I want to change a string in PHP by deleting the first and the last char but ONLY IF they are equal.

Let me give some examples:

```
' abc ' should become 'abc'
'abc a' should become 'bc '
' abc a' should not change
```

How do I do it?

Thanks for the help, the regex based solution works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the regex:

```
$str = preg_replace('~^(.)(.*)\1$~','$2',$str);
```

Regex explanation:

- `~` : Delimiters
- `^` : Start anchor
- `(.)` : match and remember a char (
  here its the first char)
- `(.*)` : match anything and remember
- `\1` : recall the first match
- `$` : End anchor
- `$2` : recall the 2nd match

Alternatively you can do:

```
// if string has >1 char and 1st and last char as same.
if(strlen($str) > 1 && $str[0] == $str[strlen($str)-1]) {
  $str = substr($str,1,strlen($str)-2); // extract the substring
}
```